# Installed Net Framework 4.5. Can build/target Framework 4.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, backwards-compatibility, .net-framework-version

I have installed [Visual Studio 2012 Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express), and .NET Framework 4.5 got installed together.

Now from Visual Studio 2012, also if I target .NET 4.0 (Properties->Application->Target Framework), that doesn't seem to work. (The same happens from Visual Studio 2010, which by the way cannot target 4.5 at all!).

What I have noticed is that if I debug my project, and set a Watch on a SqlConnection variable, I see all the new 4.5 member properties (for example I see `SqlConnection.ClientConnectionId` property, introduced with .NET 4.5).

So, what is Visual Studio -> *Properties* -> *Application* -> *Target Framework* -> *4.0* supposed to do?

Comment: With a hack, Visual Studio 2010 *can* actually target .NET 4.5: *[Targeting .NET Framework 4.5 via Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390175)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 'strange' behaviour looks, in fact, perfectly normal when you realize that the installation of .NET Framework 4.5 is a **replacement** of .NET 4.0.

Look at Stack Overflow answer *[Can a build server with .NET 4.5 installed successfully deploy a project targeting 4.0 to a server with only .NET 4.0 installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14842128/1012244)*.